# How to store data in different variable in python coming from arduino?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino-uno

Here, I am able to sent data from Arduino to python. But, here Arduino sent data of TWO variable `A0` and `A1`. And in python side, this all data store in one variable named `data`. Now how can I split data of `A0` and `A1` from `data` in python ?

Arduino Code :

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int A0 = analogRead(A0);
  int A1 = analogRead(A1);

  Serial.print(A0);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(A1);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Python Code :

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('COM12', 9600, timeout = .1)

while True:
    data = arduino.readline()

    if data:
        print data
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Arduino; you just need to split a string (`data`) into multiple (2) integers.

So `a0, a1 = map(int, data.split())` will work.